# Prove for any function $g$, $E(X(g(X))) = \mu E(g(X+1))$ if $X \sim$ Poisson($\mu$)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am currently having this:
\begin{align*}
E(Xg(X)) &= \sum xg(x) \frac{\mu^{x} e^{-\mu}}{x!} \\
&= \mu \sum g(x)\frac{\mu^{x-1}e^{-\mu}}{(x-1)!}
\end{align*}
and stucked

And I slightly doubt this identity since what if g(x) is not defined for some x?

Comment: you should pay attention to the limits of summation and things should become clear.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment, writing the ranges of the sum will be useful here.
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(Xg(X))=&\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xg(x)\dfrac{\mu^xe^{-\mu}}{x!}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{g(x)\mu^xe^{-\mu}}{(x-1)!}
\\=&\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{g(t+1)\mu^{t+1}e^{-\mu}}{t!}\hspace{1cm}\text{ writing }t=x-1
\\=&\mu\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{g(t+1)\mu^{t+1}e^{-\mu}}{t!}=\mu\mathbb{E}(g(X+1)).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Very clear. Thank you!

Comment: If you think this answers your question, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: $X\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is (non-negative) integer valued. Now, note that, any $g:\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be written as $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g(k)1\{x=k\}$. Note though that $g(\cdot)$ must be bounded (even for the original claim).

Hence, it suffices to show this when $g(\cdot)$ is of form $1\{x=k\}$ for $k$ non-negative integer, the rest follows from linearity of expectation and an appropriate convergence theorem.

Now if $g(x)=1\{x=k\}$, then $E[Xg(X)]=E[X1\{X=k\}]=kP(X=k)=ke^{-\mu}\mu^k/k!=e^{-\mu}\mu^k/(k-1)!$. Now, for $g(X+1)$, note that this object is nothing but $1\{X+1=k\}$, thus $E[g(X+1)]=E[1\{X=k-1\}]=P(X=k-1)=e^{-\mu}\mu^{k-1}/(k-1)!$. Multiplying this by $\mu$, we get the same result.

Along these lines one can also establish that: If for some constant $c>0$ and every bounded $g$, $E[Xg(X)]=cE[g(X+1)]$, then $X$ is Poisson with rate $c$.